# Unable to run jQuery file in Internet explorer extension development(BHO)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, bho

Trying to include a jQuery CDN file in my BHO file...when the project build and registered with regasm, it shows  the alert message but the jQuery file is not loaded and displays the error

Below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using SHDocVw;
using mshtml;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Greyhound.BHO
{

[
    ComVisible(true),
    Guid("8a194578-81ea-4850-9911-13ba2d71efbd"),
    ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)
]

public class BHO:IObjectWithSite
{
    SHDocVw.WebBrowser webBrowser;

    public static string BHOKEYNAME =
      "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Browser Helper Objects";

    [ComRegisterFunction]
    public static void RegisterBHO(Type type)
    {
        RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(BHOKEYNAME, true);

        if (registryKey == null)
            registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(BHOKEYNAME);

        string guid = type.GUID.ToString("B");
        RegistryKey ourKey = registryKey.OpenSubKey(guid);

        if (ourKey == null)
            ourKey = registryKey.CreateSubKey(guid);

        ourKey.SetValue("Alright", 1);
        registryKey.Close();
        ourKey.Close();
    }

    [ComUnregisterFunction]
    public static void UnregisterBHO(Type type)
    {
        RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(BHOKEYNAME, true);
        string guid = type.GUID.ToString("B");

        if (registryKey != null)
            registryKey.DeleteSubKey(guid, false);
    }

    public void OnDocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
    {
        IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)webBrowser.Document;
        doc.parentWindow.execScript("var d=window.document,s=d.createElement('script'),h=d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];s.src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js';h.appendChild(s);");
        doc.parentWindow.execScript("alert('hello');","JScript");
    }

    public int SetSite(object site)
    {
        if (site != null)
        {
            webBrowser = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser)site;
            webBrowser.DocumentComplete +=
              new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(
              this.OnDocumentComplete);
        }
        else
        {
            webBrowser.DocumentComplete -=
              new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(
              this.OnDocumentComplete);
            webBrowser = null;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public int GetSite(ref Guid guid, out IntPtr ppvSite)
    {
        IntPtr punk = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(webBrowser);
        int hr = Marshal.QueryInterface(punk, ref guid, out ppvSite);
        Marshal.Release(punk);
        return hr;
    }

}
}
```

Below is the error encountered:
[image]

The error says

> Blockquote

The object does not support the property or method "getElementsByClassName"

> Blockquote

Please let me know where I am making a mistake since I am new to BHO stuff.

Comment: I can smell here aSp.NeT \??

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird : Yup it is :)

Comment: @Adi , Then aditya , u should add it as tag ,so many users with Talent in aSp.Net will come here and solve ur ques